# .NET Roles and IIS7

Tags: .net, roles

In IIS7, I click on .NET Roles and I see a list of my Roles, but when I click a Role, no Users show up, the page is blank.  I have added the users to the role and it does show the correct count next to the role name.

Is these somehting I am missing?

Does anyone else share this problem?

Is this a bug?

Thank for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behaviour. The .NET roles section manages the role providers but not the users in roles. You will need to use the standard membership controls within pages to manage the users. think of all the management actions on the asp.net section as basically editing the web.config file. It is all about config rather than application management.

Comment: I understand wht you are syaing, but in IIS7 when you click on .NET Roles it lists the Roles, when you slecect a Role, it show 'View Users...' in the right-side Actions pane.

Why display that option if you cannot display the users?